# How to make left&right buttons work? Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help with making these two buttons work:

[image: My setup]

I watched a lot of videos on youtube, but it did not help me.

I already wrote this part of code that I would able to control my object with D and A buttons on the keyboard, but I want the user on Phone to be able to control the object with side buttons. Here is my keyboard controller:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 500f;
public float sidewaysForce = 100f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to use the component `Button`.

You can add your 2 buttons by right clicking on your `GameObject` called Canvas and select **UI/Button**.

Move one button to the left, the other to the right as you wish. Then on your 2 new GameObjects created you can safly remove the `Image` component. The buttons still remain, only the `background images` disappeared.

Now you can create 2 new methods as the following :

```cs
public void OnClickLeft(){
   rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}

public void OnClickRight(){
    rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
```

Take a look [here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button) to learn how to link your `Button` components with your methods.